# What is the proper way to load the Google Analytics tag with Angular universal?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am in the process of setting up server-side rendering for my Angular app. I followed the steps as in this [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-angular-universal), and ran the command to start the app. I received `document is not defined` caused by browser-specific objects such as `window` or `document`. I found that the error was because of the Google Analytics site tag in `index.html`. Commenting the analytics code had the app running which confirmed it was the source of the problem.

```
 <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');

  </script>
  <!--Google global site tag-->
```

I found out that one of the ways of getting around this problem is by wrapping the code around `isPlatformBrowser` `if` block. How can this be achieved in for `index.html`? What is the appropriate solution for this?

Note: This is not specific to the analytics tag, I also have other tags such as chat widget tags that are contributing to the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the scripts from `index.html` and instead inject them when your application loads, e.g. from your `AppComponent`, and only when it loads client side

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: any,  @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)
{
    if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) //Client side execution
    {
        this.injectScripts();
    }   
}

injectScripts()
{
    
    const gtmScriptTag = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    gtmScriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtmScriptTag.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXX';
    this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, gtmScriptTag);
    
    
    const gtagInitScript = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    gtagInitScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    gtagInitScript.text = `
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXX');
    `;
    this.renderer.appendChild(this._document.body, gtagInitScript);
}
```